# SPARQL: How to retrieve all dog breeds and all their infobox data from dbpedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to know how is the best sparql way to retrieve all dog breeds and all their infobox data from dbpedia.
I've tried this:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog_type> ?p ?o
}
UNION
{
  ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog_type> .
  ?s ?p ?o .
  ?p ?p2 ?o2  
}
}
```

But the result is far away from I expect like:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Basque_Shepherd_Dog dbpedia2:coat "moderately long"^^rdf:langString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog_type>` is not the class of dog *breeds.*

For several reasons, I suggest you do this work on [DBpedia Live](http://live.dpedia.org/sparql), rather than [DBpedia [Snapshot]](http://dpedia.org/sparql).

Start there with a look at the description of [your example breed, `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Basque_Shepherd_Dog`](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Basque_Shepherd_Dog).

Then consider whether [a query like the following](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fbreed%20a%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2FDogBreeds%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fbreed%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0ALIMIT%201000&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) will [get you what you want](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fbreed%20a%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2FDogBreeds%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fbreed%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0ALIMIT%201000&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) --

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
WHERE
 { 
   ?breed a  <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/DogBreeds> ;
          ?p ?o 
 }
ORDER BY ?breed ?p ?o
LIMIT 1000
```